# API c# doesn't insert number fields

Tags: soap-api, c#

I have an app that create news account in my SalesForce. All the fields are okay, unless the number fields, "int" and "double", don't throw any kind of error, just doesn't appear in SalesForce.

Some pieces of code and images:

```
            Account sfdcAccount = new Account();

            sfdcAccount.Name = "Sample from c#"; 
            sfdcAccount.OwnerId = "005240000018waEAAQ";
            sfdcAccount.Type = "Cliente";
            sfdcAccount.Id_SQL__c = 15;
            sfdcAccount.CIF__c = "43210000-X"; 
            sfdcAccount.Phone = "112"; 
            sfdcAccount.AnnualRevenue = 10; 
            sfdcAccount.NumberOfEmployees = 20; 
            sfdcAccount.ActividadEmpresa__c = "Hello"; 

            SaveResult[] saveResults = _enterpriseSoapAPIBinding.create(new sObject[] { sfdcAccount });
```

Then in salesforce appear like this:

[image]

> (Is in spanish, sorry for this, but the three fields with numbers are the 3 lasts, "NumberOfEmployees" = "Empleados", "AnnualRevenue" = "Ingresos Anuales", and Id_SQL was the custom field, Id_SQL)

As we can see, the number type fields are empty, any ideas?

Comment: did you tried with 10.0,20.0 respectively?

Comment: It failed too, btw NumberOfEmployees is a int that doesn't allow decimals.

Answer (score 1):

Any field that is not string will have a boolean property with the same name but with "Specified" appended to the end. For any non-string property you set you also need to set that "Specified" property to true.

```
Account sfdcAccount = new Account();

sfdcAccount.Name = "Sample from c#"; 
sfdcAccount.OwnerId = "005240000018waEAAQ";
sfdcAccount.Type = "Cliente";
sfdcAccount.Id_SQL__cSpecified = true;
sfdcAccount.Id_SQL__c = 15;
sfdcAccount.CIF__c = "43210000-X"; 
sfdcAccount.Phone = "112"; 
sfdcAccount.AnnualRevenueSpecified = true;
sfdcAccount.AnnualRevenue = 10; 
sfdcAccount.NumberOfEmployeesSpecified = true; 
sfdcAccount.NumberOfEmployees = 20; 
sfdcAccount.ActividadEmpresa__c = "Hello"; 

SaveResult[] saveResults = _enterpriseSoapAPIBinding.create(new sObject[] { sfdcAccount });
```